# Open Base64String in THREE.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a Javascript function that takes a base64 string as parameter. I then use the

```
window.atob(base64String);
```

function to get the binary of this file.

Essentially the data coming in is a .glb file that I pass from C# after converting it to a base64 String:

```
var buffer = await FileIO.ReadBufferAsync(file);
var bytes = buffer.ToArray();

//This is the data I pass to the JavaScript function
var result = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
```

What should I do after I get the result of the window.atob() function to get the model and display it in THREE.js? As in be able to do this:

```
scene.add(model);
```

Comment: You know you can leave out the C# element of your question altogether, since it's only tangentially related, and simply say that you have a base64-encoded .glb file in `base64string`, right?

Comment: I thought I should add it for clarity's sake.